# C string function (strcopy,strcat...,strstr) with arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Whenever I am using one of these functions in dev-C++(I know its old but for some reason still taught at my college.)

```
strcat,strcpy,strcmp,strchr...//And their variants stricmp...
```

The first argument for these functions always has to be an array (i.e:

```
char ch[]="hello";
```

But it can't be a pointer to a string bc for some reason this causes a crash.
In fact for an example look at both of these codes:

code1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{char ch[20]="Hello world!";
 char *ch2="Hello Galaxy!";
 strcat(ch,ch2);
 printf("%s",ch);
 scanf("%d")//Just to see the output.
}
```

This code works fine and gives the expected result(Hello World!Hello Galaxy!)

But the inverse code2 crashes.

code2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{char ch[20]="Hello world!";
 char *ch2="Hello Galaxy!";
 strcat(ch2,ch);
 printf("%s",ch2);
 scanf("%d")//Just to see the output.
}
```

This code crashes and causes a

```
file.exe has stopped working Error.
```

This is the same for almost all of the strings functions that takes two arguments.
What is the cause of this problem.

Comment: This isn't C++. `main` requires an explicit return type there, and your code is all C otherwise.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html

Comment: is there not a buffer overflow with `ch[20]`, shouldn't it be `ch[25]`?

Comment: @MrAnderson, 26, if I counted correctly.

Comment: Yes it is true there is overflow! But that's not where the problem comes from,in my actual code 20 was 200!Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `char *ch2 = "Hello Galaxy!";` you are obtaining a pointer to a string literal. You should never attempt to modify a string literals, as this invokes undefined behaviour (which in your case has manifested as a crash).

With `char ch[20] = "Hello World!";` you are initialising an array using the contents of a string literal, so you end up with your own modifiable copy of the string in `ch`.

Also, note that 20 characters is not enough for `Hello World!Hello Galaxy!` to fit, and this is also undefined behaviour, and known as overflowing your buffer.

Comment: Think I got it!String literals can't be modified, but contents of arrays can.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char ch[20] = "Hello world!"
```

`ch` is an array of `char` initialized by the elements of a string literal (and the rest of the array is initialized with `0`).

```
 char *ch2="Hello Galaxy!";
```

`ch2` is a pointer to a string literal.

String literals are not required to be modifiable in C. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  The first is that your string literal is not long enough to hold the concatenated string `"Hello world!Hello Galaxy!"`.  The space allocated is only 13 bytes (12 characters plus the space for the '0' byte that terminates the string).  The concatenated string requires 26 bytes (25 chars + 1 null-valued char).

However, this isn't the real problem.  The real problem is that you're accessing memory that you should not be, and that the operating system often protects.  Most implementations of C provide four areas of storage:

1. The stack, where variables you declare in a function are allocated
2. The heap, where calls to malloc/calloc/realloc allocate memory
3. Global static storage, where non-const global variables (those declared outside of a function) are allocated.
4. Global constant storage, where all string literals and other global variables declared `const` are allocated.

The first three areas are, in principle, modifiable.  The fourth area is not, and is often stored in memory that the operating system marks as read-only.  When you assign the string literal `"Hello Galaxy!" to`char* ch2`, the variable`ch2` points into global constant storage.

To give you a better idea, the following code generals a segfault when I run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* s = "Foo bar baz";
  s[0] = 'B';
  printf("%s\n",s);
  return 0;
}
```

The segfault occurs in the `s[0] = ...` line, because I'm accessing storage that the operating system has marked as read-only.

Comment: C has no stack and no heap and even does not require them to be present.

Comment: @ouah: You're right, of course.  Edited to refer to implementations. I wanted to give some non-abstract context; refering to an entirely abstract C environment doesn't help the OP understand why writing into a C literal will cause a crash.

Comment: @ouah: C does define malloc/calloc/realloc to be part of the standard library.  Is there a definition of heap (in the context of C memory management) that means something other than "the memory returned by malloc and friends"?  Similarly, the concept of stack space may be implied by the standard: variables must be allocated somewhere when a block is entered (normally or recursively), and that space is what we refer to as the stack.  The areas aren't required to be distinct, but doesn't the standard require something functionally like them to be present?

Comment: @sfstewman: Stacks are a common way to implement objects with automatic storage duration and are suitable for most architectures, but the standard doesn't require this; it may be unsuitable for some architectures (I wouldn't know, all architectures I work with utilise stacks).

Comment: @dreamlax: I realize that the standard doesn't explicitly require this, but the standard does require that blocks that are recursively entered will have new storage allocated to their variables.  Is there any way to implement this that is not stack-like?

Comment: @sfstewman: The standard describes the behaviour for objects with automatic storage. An implementation is free to handle this however it likes as long as the behaviour matches that of the standard. For example, objects with automatic storage might be allocated just as malloc would allocate them, and automatically freed at the end of the block (as long as this approach didn't violate other behavioural requirements of automatic storage).

Comment: @dreamlax: sure, but this would still be a stack-like implementation, though a non-contiguous one.  When a recursive call returns (assuming it's not tail-recursion), the previous instantiation of the variables must be recovered, so the automatic storage must behave like a LIFO structure, which is a stack.

Answer (score 0):

That is about the size of pointer array..overflow problem..
`char *ch2="Hello Galaxy!";` when you use this automaticly the size of *ch2 gets 14 with the null character but when you move the `ch[]` array into the `*ch2` , you get an error. you cannot move an array with 20 size into another array with 14 size...

Answer (score 0):

String literals are read-only.This means that if you assign:

```
char* str="Hello";
```

You can't pass str as first argument of strcpy and strcat, because this would cause to write over read-only memory.
If instead you declare it this way:

```
char str2[]="Hello";
```

Then the str2 array is stored on the stack, and you can change it's values.
You can still pass str to functions like strcmp (which just reads the wto strings and compare them), or as second argument of strcat and strcpy, since this doesn't cause the string to be written.

Answer (score 0):

you got an error because you try to access the code section of your process which is read-only.
that is your string literal present in code and the address of that string literal you use in assignment to your pointer variable.
So you can access the code but you  cannot modify this.

every executable file contain some sections
like...

1.text(code of your program as well as string literals present here)

2.data uninitialized

3.data initialized

you can veryfy this by command

```
size <executable-file-neme>
```

Also using command

```
objdump -D  <executable-file-neme>
```